# ADB manual restore?

Tags: applications, adb, samsung, backup

I've tried to do a full restore for a while now but i keep getting stuck on a specific app and when unpacking the backup and removing it a new problem occurs which is my phone being restarting when using the adb restore command.

is it possible to restore apps and files manually with ADB from an unpacked .AB file?

[logcat](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6fbljzrky75akhk/logcat.txt?dl=0)

Comment: If your device is rooted, you can use Titanium Backup to restore selected contents from backup files. Without root, I'm not aware of any such solution.

Comment: @Izzy♦ i tried to use titanium but it told me that the adb backup was unsupported or something similar

Comment: Then I don't know. TiBu is supposed to be able to extract stuff from ADB backups, though I never tried it myself (I only make "granular backups" with ADB, so I can restore just the pieces I want).